# TvOS UITabBarController detect tabbar shown/hidden

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tvos, apple-tv

Is there anyway to detect that the tabbar of a UITabBarController is going to appear or disappear? I want to make an animation simultaneously with the animation that shows/hides the tabbar.

I haven't find any way to detect this event. The property "hidden" of the tabbar is not an option because it changes its value once the animation has finished

Comment: You can use viewController's viewWillAppear to detect tab will change. And you can send a notification or you can use delegate to detect it in your UITabBarController

Comment: But in TvOS it is possible to show the tabbar without changing the view controller (just pressing menu button or going uo with the remote trakpad) and in this cases I won't be able to detect that tab bar is shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to use the method in the view controller didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator: with this code:

```
static NSString *kUITabBarButtonClassName = @"UITabBarButton";

NSString *prevFocusViewClassName = NSStringFromClass([context.previouslyFocusedView class]);
    NSString *nextFocusedView = NSStringFromClass([context.nextFocusedView class]);

    // The tabbar is going to disappear
    if ([prevFocusViewClassName isEqualToString:kUITabBarButtonClassName] &&
        ![nextFocusedView isEqualToString:kUITabBarButtonClassName]) {
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        self.constraintScrollViewCenterY.constant -= self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;

        [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:nil];
    // The tabbar is going to appear
    } else if (![prevFocusViewClassName isEqualToString:kUITabBarButtonClassName] &&
               [nextFocusedView isEqualToString:kUITabBarButtonClassName]) {
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        self.constraintScrollViewCenterY.constant += self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;

        [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:nil];
    }
```

where self.constraintScrollViewCenterY is a constraint related to the vertical alignment of the view I want to move according to the tabbar movement

Note: The use of class name (kUITabBarButtonClassName) instead of [... class] method is due to UITabBarButton is a private class

Comment: I have multiple view controllers for my tab bar. This would mean I would have to write this code in each of the view controllers

Comment: Yes, you should have to use this code in all the viewcontrollers. Maybe you could use a base class with this code from which inherit